# Google Slides Editor Add-on: Translate

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-slides

I'm working off of this sample [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/slides/quickstart/translate) to help a teacher translate a Google Slides presentation into another language to support a student. The translation function works great. In the presentation, there are some key terms underlined that indicate to the students what should be filled in on their notes pages. Unfortunately, after translating the slide, the formatting will also be modified. For example, if the slide starts with an underlined word, all words that follow will be underlined. For this teacher's specific purpose, the slides then become pretty much useless.

I'm new to Google Apps Script, but was wondering if anyone knew of a way to preserve the formatting? Any guidance you could provide would be appreciated!